# Getting HTTP response code -1 from POST request

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to upload a file to a server and I keep getting a error response code of -1.

This is for a NativeScript app built with Angular and I'm using the NativeScript HTTP Background plugin.

component.ts

```
onCreateRecipe() {
      console.log(this.imageUris);

    const recipeForm = { 
      name: this.form.get('name').value, 
      description: this.form.get('description').value, 
      photo: this.imageUris[0], 
      ingredients: this.form.get('ingredients').value,       
      // steps: this.form.get('steps').value,
      // tag: 'poultry recipe'
      type: this.recipeType
    };
    console.log(recipeForm);
    this.apiService.postRecipe(recipeForm).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

service.ts

```
postRecipe(recipe) {
    const session = bghttp.session('image-upload');
    const subject = new Subject<any>();

    const request = {
      url: `${this.apiURL}/recipe/1`,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
      },
      description: 'test'
    };

    let task: bghttp.Task;
    const params = [
      { name: 'name', value: recipe.name },
      { name: 'description', value: recipe.description },
      { name: 'photo', filename: recipe.photo, mimeType: 'image/png' },
      { name: 'ingredients', value: JSON.stringify(recipe.ingredients) }
    ];
    console.log(params);
    task = session.multipartUpload(params, request);
    task.on('responded', (event: any) => {
      if (event.data && event.data.error) {
        subject.error(event.data);
      } else {
        subject.next(event.data);
      }
    });
    // task.on('error', (event) => subject.error(event));
    task.on('error', (e) =>console.log("received " + e.responseCode + " code."));
    return subject;
  }
```

Note: ingredients is a FormArray that's why I have to use JSON.Stringify to pass it to the plugin. recipe.photo is a file path to the image.

I expect all the data, including the image file, to be uploaded to the server but right now only the image is being uploaded.

Comment: A -1 as response code sounds like a CORS issue. Please double check wether this is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's the issue because I'm able to send GET requests from the server. But, I'll make sure that isn't the issue.